# gateway ocelot API doesn't work .NET 6 ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, ocelot

I'm creating a project with microservices and now I want to be able to test the API gateway with ocelot API every time I try to access  `https://localhost:4482/gateway/product` give me
"can't reach this page"

ocelot.json:

```
{
  "ReRoutes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/product",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 44
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/gateway/product",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET"]
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/Order",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 44
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/gateway/Order",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET", "PUT", "POST" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Gateway.Program.cs

```
using Ocelot.DependencyInjection;
using Ocelot.Middleware;



var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("ocelot.json");
// Add services to the container.


builder.Services.AddControllers();

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddOcelot();
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseOcelot().Wait();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

I'm missing something but can't figure out what it is, I have checked the downstream path and upstream path.
I would be grateful for any help

Comment: Your configuration is set to port 44, try doing http://localhost:44/

Comment: @hallie it should be the "sslPort" => "4482" in the launchsettings.json of the Gateway service to get the results directly from the microservice (which is located at localhost:44)

Comment: Are you able to make a `GET` request to the downstream service at `https://localhost:44/api/product` and receive `product` using postman or a browser?  If you can then probably there may be an issue with your ocelot config in the gateway.

Comment: Not familiar with `Ocelot` but wondering do you also need to specify the downstream HttpMethod like you have the UpstreamHttpMethod.  Something like `"DownstreamHttpMethod": ["GET"]`

Comment: Rename `ReRoutes` to `Routes`

Answer (score 4):

In .net core 6, from ocelot 17.0.1 you have to use "Routes" instead "ReRoute"

and you can put it directly in the appsettings.json

I assume that under your solution you have a project similar to this

[image]

here the samples

**appsettings.json**

```html
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Routes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/product",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 44
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/gateway/product",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET" ]
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/Order",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 44
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/gateway/Order",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET", "PUT", "POST" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**program.cs**

```html
using Ocelot.DependencyInjection;
using Ocelot.Middleware;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddOcelot();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseOcelot();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

let me know if it works.